# Working with a bitmap image in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a jpg image. First i want to convert it to bitmap so that i can get all pixels from my picture.
Then i want to keep the pixels into a two dimensional array as row and column of a matrix.
Then i want to search either row or column or both to match with a color.That means i want to find if a row(or a column whatever i want) of that 2D matrix contains RED color(for example).  I tried something like this:

```
          Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.laser);
      bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);          

      int[] pixels = new int[bmp.getHeight()*bmp.getWidth()];
      bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());

            for(int i =0; i<pixels.length;i++){       
           if(pixels[i]==0xffff0000)
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
              }
```

Here i took pixels into an array(1D) and check if a red color is exist or not in that array.
But it didn't find although red color exists in my pic.
Here may be the array cant get pixels. 
But this is not what i want. What i want mentioned above. How can i reach my goal???

Comment: I want it in android phone

Comment: OpenCV has ported to Android. You can install the libraries with an app called OpenCV Manager, available in the Google Play Store. The Java interfaces to OpenCV can be packed in an .apklib, so that your IDE can find them.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a Bitmap object, you can get pixels using [Bitmap::getPixels](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method.
for example, here i get first column of an image:

```
    // byte[] data2 contains image binary date from the network
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data2, 0, data2.length);

    int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getHeight()];

    int offset = 0;
    int stride = 1;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = 1;
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, offset, stride, x, y, width, height);
```

each pixels is just an [Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) object so you can check it's RGB values.

Comment: Would you tell me how can i compare my desired RGB values with rows RGB values?? @pelotasplus

Comment: iterate over row/column and check values?  let's say you want match a column/row with only red pixels, then your code might look like this:

`for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    if (! Color.red[pixels[i] == 255 || Color.green(pixels[i]) || Color.blue(pixels[i])) {
        // aha, pixels at position i is not full red.
     }
}`

very simple loop, you have to adapt it to suit your needs

Comment: Was my mentioned method to convert a normal image to bitmap correct ??? @pelotasplus